# XUnit.net test cases not displaying in test explorer in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xunit.net

I am beginner for xunit testing. 
My colleague has installed xunit from nuget packages of visual studio 2013 update 3. Then he did the unit testing and checked in everything in SVN.
When I took the updated code from SVN, it shows me everything fine.
But, when I am running the individual test case, test case is not running.
Also, Test explorer is not showing any test from test project.
Please let me know the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using v1 or v2? Take a look at http://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-vs.html especially the top notes

Answer (score 0):

I was trying for installaing xunit runner from nuget packages so test explorer was not showing the unit test cases. I took the older version of xunit runner and installed. It works for me! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.0+ NuGet package then try to delete folder like *xunit.runner.visualstudio.0.99.9-build1021* with obsolete runner from your NuGet *packages* folder if such exists.